# Is JPWO2011145301A1 patent granted?

Tags: publicationorgranted

The status of this [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/JPWO2011145301A1/en?oq=jpwo2011145301a1) is "granted" but I think that this patent document is just publication. if it is granted patent, please let me know where I can find the patent document.

[image]

Comment: I do see in the Global Dossier via Espacenet that a counterpart US patent was granted US8568925B2.

Answer (score 1):

Information at the Japan Patent Office (https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/h0000), and the Global Dossier (https://globaldossier.uspto.gov/#/result/application/JP/2012515738/125790), indicate that this Japanese patent application was withdrawn on March 21, 2013.

Comment: This is helpful. Providing a link to the specified page(s) would make it better.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I edited the answer with the links.

Comment: The hyperlink tool (third icon from the left in the editor) allows you to highlight a phrase and then apply a URL. This makes the phrase highlight and lead you to the page without the unsightly URL showing up. Makes reading questions and answers easier.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I'll eventually get it.